# Getting Multiple IPC callbacks From Single IPC Call

Tags: typescript, electron, axios, ipc

Main:

```js
ipcMain.on('botCheckLogin', (event: Electron.IpcMessageEvent, token: string) => {
    axios.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify' +
    '?secret=serverSecret=' + token)
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        event.sender.send('botCheckLoginReturn', 'hi');
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        event.sender.send('botCheckLoginReturn', 'world');
    });
});
```

Render:

```js
submitForm() {
    if ((this.$refs.form as LoginForm).validate()) {
        this.$recaptcha('login').then((token) => {
            console.log('sending token!');
            IPC.send('botCheckLogin', token);
        });

        IPC.on('botCheckLoginReturn', (event: Electron.IpcMessageEvent, response: any) => {
            console.log(response);
            return;
            const loginPacket: LoginPacket = {
                userName: (this as LoginForm).userName,
                displayName: (this as LoginForm).displayName,
                password: (this as LoginForm).loginPassword,
                email: (this as LoginForm).email,
            };
            if (!(this as LoginVar).isRegister) {
                IPC.send('login', loginPacket);
            } else {
                IPC.send('register', loginPacket);
            }
        });
     }
}
```

The function `submitForm` is called by a button. I clicked that button 4 times, waiting for the MAIN process to respond before clicking again, and this is what I get on the console:

```
sending token!
hi
sending token!
(2x) hi
sending token!
(3x) hi
sending token!
(4x) hi
```

The `sending token` text is logged on button press, and the `hi` is the returned text from the MAIN process. It should only be returning `hi` once. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attaching a new event handler for `botCheckLoginReturn` each time you click the button. This list of event handlers is extended each time you click the button. Each of this growing list of event handlers is then called upon the event.

Make sure the following is only executed "once":

```
IPC.on('botCheckLoginReturn', (event: Electron.IpcMessageEvent, response: any) => {
    console.log(response);
    // ...
});
```

That means, move it out of the code called when you press the button.

Comment: Oh got it! Thanks!